# How to select using criteria? SQL syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have been learning SQL for a couple of weeks now but at the moment there is a problem I really can't solve alone. I am not sure whether I have formulated the problem in the title properly so let me explain it. 
 So, basically, I have a Table (lets call it ***Table1***), which has fields: ***Width, Height, Length***. I have a form (lets call it ***Form1***), which has three text boxes: ***X, Y, Z*** with basic values 0 in each of them and I need to perform a search query. However, let's say that I have entered a value only in ***X*** and ***Y*** and ***Z*** are 0.

For example: 
X = 255; Y = 0 (basic value); Z = 0 (basic value); 
And I need to select all those records from Table1, which have Width = 255.
But if there are values, different from 0, in all of the three text boxes, I need to select those records who have Width = X, Height = Y, Length = Z;

I am not sure whether I explained it clearly so there is a pseudo code:

```
IF (X != 0 AND Y != 0 AND Y != 0)
THEN SELECT Table1.* WHERE (Width = X AND Height = Y AND Length = Z)
ELSE IF (X == 0 AND Y != 0 AND Z != 0)
THEN SELECT Table1.* WHERE (Height = Y AND Length = Z)
and so on with all combinations....
```

So my question is: how should I write this in SQL? 
Thank you for the answers and excuse me for the mistakes I have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for something like

```
Select Table1.*
from Table1
where (X = 0 or Width = X) and
      (Y = 0 or Height = Y) and
      (Z = 0 or Length = Z)
```

as 0 = 0 will be true, you won't mind X if it's equal to zero...